# What's the best workaround for not having "cabal upgrade"?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to upgrade all packages, not just a specific one with `cabal install --upgrade-dependencies`.

Comment: You know cabal upgrade was removed for a reason, right?  This will likely break all your packages, sooner or later.

Comment: You should just use cabal-dev, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev

Comment: @John L yep, it's gotten quite nice.

Comment: For reference, `cabal`s new integrated `sandbox` function should be able to replace `cabal-dev` for almost all usecases. See [this blog post](http://coldwa.st/e/blog/2013-08-20-Cabal-sandbox.html)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This bit of shell hackery works for me on OS X:

```
cabal list --simple-output --installed | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | xargs -I {} cabal install {} --reinstall
```

**EDIT**: Now forces a reinstall, and avoids installing a package more than once when more than one version is present. Thanks for the comments!

**EDIT YEARS LATER**: Now that Cabal sandboxes and Stack exist, I strongly recommend against trying to upgrade packages in place. You'll end up with far fewer headaches if you instead can just wipe out an existing sandbox and reinstall up-to-date dependencies.

Comment: Don't forget the `--reinstall` flag on that last `cabal install` command.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `uniq` filter after the `awk` step? At least in my environment it would call `cabal install` multiple times with the same argument... also, it might not be desirable to upgrade the system libraries bundled with GHC, such as `base`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, @acfoltzer. Should the `--reinstall` in the command change to `--force-reinstall`? I currently have cabal with version 1.16.0.2. When I upgrade all packages, it constantly reminds that "The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls...<the list of packages>... Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway."

Comment: As far as I understand, `cabal install` lies. The better approach would be to use `ghc-pkg list --user`, so you never touch GHC global packages.

Comment: Is this still a valid approach? [Is there a better alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32077856/656912) It seems odd (stupid actually) that Cabal provides no way to keep package uptodate!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius at this point, I would recommend using Cabal sandboxes or Stack, which are easy to wipe and start over, rather than reinstalling new versions in existing package databases

Answer (score 7):

The `.cabal/world` file contains a list of every package you installed explicitly (listed in a `cabal install` command, as opposed to pulled through dependencies).  Trim it to remove packages that are only useful as dependencies, packages that are deprecated, and version-locked packages that you'd rather upgrade.

Cabal doesn't know how to clean-up after itself, but you can remove almost everything. The next command will reinstall from `.cabal/packages` (a tarball cache):

```sh
cp -t bin .cabal/bin/cabal
rm -rf .cabal/{bin,lib,share} .ghc/*-*-*/
ghc-pkg check |&egrep -- '^[A-Za-z0-9-]+-[0-9]' |xargs -n1 --no-run-if-empty ghc-pkg unregister
```

Now reinstall everything that was manually installed:

```sh
cabal install world --upgrade-dependencies --force-reinstalls
```