# Upgrade dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have an application in a sandbox. Cabal dependencies have no constraints so `cabal install --only-dependencies` gives me the latest packages.
After a certain period of time I want to bump my dependencies to the latest versions but before this I want to see which dependencies are actually changed to a newer version.
I can check all of them manually of course. But I'd rather see a nice list of the things that will be upgraded.

I assume that `cabal install --upgrade-dependencies --only-dependencies --dry-run` is the way to do it. I would expect it to give me the list of all the packages that are at newer version that the one in my sandbox. But it never works! I mean, it just says that all dependencies are up to date when they are clearly not. Am I doing something wrong or missing/misunderstanding something?

If I destroy my sandbox completely, rerun `cabal install --only-dependencies` and diff the freeze files then I can see which packages got bumped. But this is silly. So how can I get `cabal install --upgrade-dependencies --only-dependencies --dry-run` to work correctly and print all the packages that are going to be upgraded without blowing the sandbox? Ad if those options do not work in cabal why aren't they just removed to avoid confusion?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate(? - well maybe not 100%) and/or this could help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905163/whats-the-best-workaround-for-not-having-cabal-upgrade

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. It does not answer the question at all. I know I can do tricks with sed, bash, ruby and what not. My question is about cabal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cabal list --installed` and compare "Default available version" with "Installed versions".

Unfortunately cabal's `--simple-output` switch does not include that information, so to automate it you will need a smallish script.